# Incrementing variable by 1 when button is pressed

Tags: python, tkinter, button

I've been trying to figure out tkinter as I need it for my computer science project so I'm still very new to it but I'm trying to make a button that when pressed, a variable is increased and outputted with the changed amount.

This was the original code I tried:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

item_num = 0


def AddButton():
    global item_num
    item_num =+ 1
    item_text = "Item "+ item_num
    item1 = Label(receiptFrame, text=item_text, padx=25, pady=10)
    item1.pack()

addButton = Button(root, text="Add Button", padx=25, pady=25, command=AddButton)
addButton.pack()

receiptFrame = Frame(root, width=70, height=30)
receiptFrame.pack()

root.mainloop
```

When I press the button this comes up:

item_text = "Item "+ item_num

TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

I tried using another solution I found on here using IntVar(), set & get but when run it I get:

TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "IntVar") to str

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

item_num = 0
item_num = IntVar()

def AddButton():
    global item_num
    item_num.set(item_num.get()+1)
    item_num = int(item_num)
    item_text = "Item "+ item_num
    item1 = Label(receiptFrame, text=item_text, padx=25, pady=10)
    item1.pack()

addButton = Button(root, text="Add Button", padx=25, pady=25, command=AddButton)
addButton.pack()

receiptFrame = Frame(root, width=70, height=30)
receiptFrame.pack()

root.mainloop
```

I also did try putting item_num into the function as a parameter using lambda but when I did that the button couldn't be pressed at all so again, I'm not sure what went wrong there

Again, I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing so I'd appreciate any semi-beginner solutions aha :)

Comment: It should be `item_num += 1` and `item_text = "Item",item_num`.

Comment: I think you mean `item_text = "Item "+ str(item_num)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `+` for concatenation, which is the problem because both side of the `+` requires to be a string. Also you had other problems, like:

- You used `=+ 1`, which means the value is +1(positive 1) always, which should be `+= 1` so it gets increased by 1 each time.
- Also you forgot to put `()` at the end of `mainloop()`.
- You are creating a new label each time you click on the button, instead make a label and change its text.

So the final formatted code is:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

item_num = 0
def AddButton():
    global item_num

    item_num += 1 # Add current value plus 1
    item_text = "Item"+str(item_num) 
    item1.config(text=item_text) # Change the text of the label
    print(item_text)

item1 = Label(root, padx=25, pady=10) # Make the label for the first time
item1.pack()
# Same code...

root.mainloop() # Important ()
```

There are other ways you can use write `item_text`, like:

```
item_text = "Item"+str(item_num) # This returns a string
item_text = "Item",item_num # This returns a tuple
item_text = f'Item{item_num}' # This returns a string
item_text = "Item{}".format(item_num) # This returns a string as well
```

Comment: btw your statement "Both side of the `+` requires to be of same `type`" is technically incorrect as you can add objects of type `<int>`and `<float>`. You can also define the `__add__` magic method in your custom class so that you can add object of that type to any other types of objects.

Comment: @thelizzard Yes that makes sense, I was talking about concatenation and forgot it half way there, my bad.